# How to untar in Emacs dired?

Tags: emacs, tar

Is there a simple way to untar files in Emacs Dired? Currently I'm doing a `M-! tar -xvf <filename>`, however I feel like there is be an easier way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `dired` extensively you should take a look at [Dired Extra](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-zh?action=browse;oldid=DiredX;id=DiredExtra) (it comes with Emacs), it has a feature that allows Emacs to guess what to do with files, e.g. just press <kbd>!</kbd> with the archive selected and the prompt will suggest `tar xvf`, so a simple <kbd>Return</kbd> will do the job.

Just add this snippet to your `~/.emacs` to load `dired-x` together with `dired`:

```
(add-hook 'dired-load-hook (function (lambda () (load "dired-x"))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this EmacsWiki page, it points towards a dired-tar package that should do what you want:
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPower#toc4